# After submission of Form data, I am Unable to clear the form fields to empty

Tags: redux, react-hook-form

I have a form and I am submitting the form values to the Server, But Right after submitting the data, I called a "HandleClear()" function to clear the form fields, But stills selected values is shown after submitting the Data..
When I console log, I am bale to see that Data is getting cleared..

```
 const [data, setdata] = useState({
        "UserName": "",
        "PhoneNumber": "",
        "email": "",
        "dropDown": "",
        "gender": null,
        "checking": [],
        //    "id" :""
    })
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(allActions.createData(data));
        handleClear();
        //setmodel(false);
    }
```

This is HandleClear function

```
 const handleClear=()=>{
        let clear={
            "UserName": "",
            "PhoneNumber": "",
            "email": "",
            "dropDown": "",
            "gender": null,
            "checking": [],
        }
        //console.log(clear);
          setdata(clear);
    }
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="container">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={adduser}>Add User</button>
                </div>
                {model && (
                    <div className="modal" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                        <div className="modal-dialog" style={{ maxWidth: "60%" }}>
                            <div className="modal-content">
                                <div className="modal-header">
                                    <h5 className="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onClick={closeModal}></button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div className="row">
                                            <div className="col">
                                                <div className="mb-3" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                                                    <label className="form-label fw-bold">UserName</label>
                                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder='UserName' name="UserName" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="mb-3" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                                                    <label className="form-label fw-bold">PhoneNumber</label>
                                                    <input name="phone" className="form-control" placeholder='PhoneNumber' name="PhoneNumber" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="mb-3" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                                                    <label className="form-label fw-bold">Email</label>
                                                    <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder='EmailAddress' id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="email" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                </div>
                                                {/* <div className="mb-3">
                        <label
                          htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1"
                          className="form-label"
                        >
                          Date
                        </label>
                        <input
                          type="date"
                          className="form-control"
                          id="exampleInputPassword1"
                        />
                        </div> */}
    
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="col">
                                                <div className="mb-3" style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                                                    <label className="fw-bold">DropDown Value</label>
                                                    <select className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="dropDown" onChange={handleChnage} >
                                                        <option >Select From Dropdown</option>
                                                        <option value="ReactJS">ReactJS</option>
                                                        <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
                                                        <option value="HtmlCss">HtmlCss</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="mb-3">
                                                    <label className="mb-2 fw-bold">Gender</label>
                                                    <div className="form-check">
                                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexRadioDefault1" >Male</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="form-check">
                                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexRadioDefault2">Female</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="form-check">
                                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="others" value="others" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexRadioDefault2">Others</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="mb-3">
                                                    <label className="mb-2 fw-bold">Checkbox Value</label>
                                                    <div className="form-check">
                                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking"  value="Javascript" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckDefault">Javascript</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="form-check">
                                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking" value="React JS" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckChecked">React JS</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="form-check">
                                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking"  value="HTML" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckChecked">HTML</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="form-check">
                                                        <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checking"  value="CSS" onChange={handleChnage} />
                                                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexCheckChecked">CSS</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={closeModal}>Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>Add User</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add Value Attribute to the Form Fields